# Removing trailing comma while rendering elements in array.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any simple way of removing the trailing comma in the below snippet

```
const renderElements = () => {
    if (!(data && data.length)) return [];
    return data.map(({ id, name }, index) => (
      <p key={id}>{`${name}${
        !(index === data.length - 1) ? "," : ""
      }`}</p>
    ));
}


return (
 <div>
  {renderElements()}
</div>
)
```

Comment: You can use CSS to add content before or after element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine, so why bother to find another way to write it?

But perhaps, you don't need to insert the comma manually, just leave it to css:

```js
const renderElements = () => {
    if (!(data && data.length)) return [];
    return data.map(({ id, name }) => (
      <p key={id}>{name}</p>
    ));
}


return (
  <div>
    {renderElements()}
  </div>
);
```

```css
div p {
  display: inline;
}

div p:not(:last-of-type)::after {
  content: ',';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Alice</p>
  <p>Bob</p>
  <p>Charlie</p>
  <p>David</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly I just commented under answer

Comment: Lol, we thought the same thing